# how to skip document.querySelectorAll value is null or does not exist

Tags: if-statement, schema, google-tag-manager

```js
<script>
(function(){
    var data = {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Movie",
  "actor": [],
for (i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('span.movie-cast-title').length; i++) 
{
  if (!document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')[i]) {
        data.actor.push({
    "@type": "PerformanceRole",
    "actor": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": document.querySelectorAll('span.movie-cast-title')[i].innerText,
      "url": document.querySelectorAll('a.movie-cast-url')[i].href,

      
    },
    "characterName": document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')[i].innerText,
          
        });
  }
  else
  {
  data.actor.push({
    "@type": "PerformanceRole",
    "actor": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": document.querySelectorAll('span.movie-cast-title')[i].innerText,
      "url": document.querySelectorAll('a.movie-cast-url')[i].href,  
    },
     });
        
  }  
  };
var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "application/ld+json";
  script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
})(document);
</script>
```

how to skip "characterName": document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')[i].innerText, value is empty. for is const characterName is doest not exist skip only the characterName var. if else statement is correct or using other any statement?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to create a an object that will store the attributes that are always present. Then, if *characterName* isn't empty, add this attribute to the object and push it to the *data.actor* array:

```
var actor = {
    "@type": "PerformanceRole",
    "actor": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": document.querySelectorAll('span.movie-cast-title')[i].innerText,
      "url": document.querySelectorAll('a.movie-cast-url')[i].href      
    }
}

if (!document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')[i])
    actor["characterName"] = document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')[i].innerText

data.actor.push(actor)
```